# SugarCRM 7 disable the autosearch on every key press on List views. SugarCRM 7

Tags: sugarcrm

Is there a way to disable the autosearch on every key press on listview? . Or if there is no way to disable it , is there a way to extend the time that the Ajax request is called?. I am using SugarCRM 7